# Setting viewing position in Matplotlib 3d scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d, geometry

I have a set of points inside a 3d cube. I want to get a visual projection of those points in 2d depending on where the observer is. So far I've been trying to plot my points in 3d and set elevation and azimuth such that I'm viewing a cube on the side.

This is a simple example, but I need to be able to generalise my code for any (x,y,z) position of the observer. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

coord = np.random.uniform(2.,4., (10000,3)) # cube points

los = np.array([10.,3.,3])  #observer position ( looking at side of cube)

center = np.array([3.,3.,3.]) #cube center

def elev(los, target):
    diff = target - los
    cosel = np.sum(los*diff)/np.sqrt(np.sum(los**2.) *  np.sum(diff**2.))
    el = np.degrees(np.arccos(cosel))
    return el

def azi(los, target):
    diff = target - los
    cosazi = (-los[2]*los[0]*diff[0] - los[2]*los[1]*diff[1] + \\
(los[0]**2.+los[1]**2)*diff[2]) / np.sqrt((los[0]**2.+los[1]**2.)* \\
(los[0]**2.+los[1]**2.+los[2]**2)*(diff[0]**2.+diff[1]**2.+diff[2]**2)) 
    sinazi = (-los[2]*diff[0] + los[0]*diff[1]) /  \\
np.sqrt((los[0]**2.+los[1]**2.)*(diff[0]**2.+diff[1]**2.+diff[2]**2.))
    tanazi = sinazi/cosazi
    azi = np.degrees(np.arctan(tanazi))
    return azi

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(coord[:,0], coord[:,1], coord[:,2], edgecolor = "none", alpha = 0.3)

ax.view_init(elev=elev(los, center), azim=azi(los,center))
plt.show()
```

I should be seeing a perfect square, but my resulting view point is at an angle. What's going wrong?

I've borrowed elevation and azimuth formulae from here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58923/calculate-view-angle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the elevation and the azimuth in matplotlib are with respect to the axes origin, not the center of the object drawn. It is then necessary to transform the coordinates of the object into the origin and transform the point of view with respect to the object.

Then the azimuth and the elevation are very easy to get by converting the observer position to spherical polar coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Note: elevation theta is measured from reference plane, so theta = arcsin(z/r)  (instead of arccos). The azimuth will need to be corrected depending on which quadrant the observer is in.